# Prevent Google Web Preview bot

Tags: user-agent, robots.txt, googlebot

I noticed today in the webserver logs that we sometimes get *bursts* (`450 requests in 2 seconds`) of requests from a useragent with `Google Web Preview`. Looking at [other stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45826598/useragent-google-web-preview-bot-or-not) it seems this is probably related to the preview functionality on the search page or *maybe* to the saved/most used links at the bottom of a users chrome tabs.

I've already blocked these particular URLs in the `robots.txt`, so, it's obviously ignoring that. It seems from [this 2010 instant previews page](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2010/11/instant-previews) that you can add a `nosnippet` tag and Google will then not try to fetch the preview. However, it seems that adding `nosnippet` wouldn't actually stop the request (as they'd still have to fetch the page to parse out the tag).

Short of blocking Google's ip address which I don't want to do, is there a decent way to stop Google hammering the server periodically.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably did it, but when I get such issue I make a buffer page, and provide link on that page e.g link for admin panel that I don't want to be rendered and use NO Index on that page